# How and why does DOSBox work the way it does?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, emulation, dosbox

As a complete novice when it comes to the topic of emulation or virtual machines, I was presented with the following two questions that I need to answer:

1. Briefly explain how software (in this example DOSBox) replaces some hardware/CPU functions.
2. What was the rationale behind doing it this way?

When trying to think of an aspect of this emulator that I could discuss, I came across the following sentence:

"Since DOSBox can emulate its CPU by interpretation, the environment it emulates is completely independent of the host CPU."

However, I cannot find the answer to what emulation by interpretation means and what the benefits are of the environment being independent of the host CPU.

Could someone please help me understand it, or suggest another part of DOSBox that is worth talking about in my answer?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: I do not understand why my question got closed for being off-topic. First of all, I got told to post it here by a moderator from Stack Overflow. Second of all I am clearly not asking for software recommendations. I am just trying to understand how a certain type of software works. But "if you have a hammer everything looks like a nail" I guess, and that's how a lot of moderators on these forums seem to operate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what emulation by interpretation means

It means that when you run a DOS program inside DOSbox, it isn't directly given to the CPU to execute – instead its instructions are read as *data* by DOSbox itself. For every instruction that it reads, DOSbox then executes code that does the same thing but on the real CPU.

A better example would be e.g. PDP-11 emulators or Atari emulators.

> what the benefits are of the environment being independent of the host CPU

It means you can run 16-bit DOS programs on CPUs which don't support the necessary 16-bit modes (e.g. when the main OS is running in 64-bit mode), and even on CPUs that aren't x86 architecture at all (e.g. ARM or RISC-V CPUs).

The downside is that it'll be slower, but for emulating old systems it's acceptable,

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes much more sense now :)